# How to search for Greek words in LXX/Septuagint?

Tags: discussion

I want to study how the Greek words ἄλλος (243) and ἕτερος (2087) are used in the LXX but I do not know of any resources to search and find these words. Are there any online sources to do this? Or Bibleworks or any other program? I tried BW on someone's computer but could never find how to search the LXX.

Comment: Googling "Septuagint concordance download" finds lots of hits (e.g.(https://ia600306.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/4/items/aconcordancetos00redpgoog/aconcordancetos00redpgoog_tif.zip&file=aconcordancetos00redpgoog_tif/aconcordancetos00redpgoog_0007.tif&id=aconcordancetos00redpgoog&scale=8&rotate=0), but the ones I looked at were all scans, and so not searchable.

Comment: biblearc.com and stepbible.org

Answer (score 1):

If by BW you mean Bible Works, you first need to chose BGT as the search version. Then in the search box you type . or ' and then immediately the word WITHOUT ACCENTS. If you also want to see the different inflections then type * instead of the last letters. SO your search should be looking something like

> 'αλλ*

> 'ετερ*

Otherwise, there is the hard way. This is a link to the [whole Bible in Ancient Greek](http://www.imgap.gr/file1/AG-Pateres/PDhiathiki1.html) but you can only search each chapter at a time.

Or, you could download [this PDF version of the Bible in Ancient Greek](https://www.openbook.gr/agia-grafi/) and search there.

Answer (score 1):

[Stepbible.org](https://www.stepbible.org/?q=version=ESV%7Cversion=SBLG%7Cversion=LXX%7Cstrong=G2087&options=VGUVNH&display=INTERLEAVED&pos=1) is very useful. You can type the word in allos, eteros, and it will show the Greek keywords.

[Blueletterbible](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/inflections.cfm?strongs=G3062&t=NIV&ot=LXX&word=%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B9%CF%80%E1%BD%B0) site provides the best feature for word search where you can convert all Greek word results to an English version, but Brenton's English LXX is not available. Just put the desired strong's code in the link or search that word then click on the word to show its occurrences in each of its forms.

The same can be searched on theword.net Bible software, by searching for the Strong's code like G2087 for heteros, on a LXX module with Strong's embedded. I have Apostolic Bible Polyglot ABP Interlinear version, which can give me the result, where I don't have to compare the English as it's interlinear.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the LXX in the Blue Letter Bible, https://www.blueletterbible.org/lxx/isa/58/6/t_concr_737006 and if you have the Greek keyboard on your device (or a place to copy the Greek text you're searching for), you can search by word.

For instance, you wanted to search for ἄλλος....I just copied the text with accent from your question, dropped it in the search box and got back 9 instances of that word being used in the LXX.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that STEP is mostly great and very easy to use. It will do your *heteros* / *allos* very easily. Every instance.
However, it has serious limitations. That's why I'm looking for an alternative.

1. Incomplete lexicon. Lexicon includes only the full NT lexicon and a number of other words. However, try searching for *ἡμίονον* - mule. It's not in STEP's lexicon, which for some reason means I can't see a list of all the instances. Searching for *χωνευτήριον*, same problem.
2. The exact word feature has never worked properly; e.g. try *egeneto*. Sure, you can just paste the Greek script into the search bar. But the search rarely if ever works.
   Fallback: do the verb *ginomai* and use Ctrl+F in Chrome to find *egeneto*; slow, but it works.
3. You can't search for a phrase of three words together. As *ti emoi kai soi* or "*ἀπὸ υἱῶν Ἰσραήλ*"
   Fallback: Google. It's exhausting and you never know if you found them all.
4. Less important. I wish I could search for cognates in one search, e.g. *zume* / *zumow*.